# I want to play miniclip multiplayer 8ball pool but can't !

Tags: google

I can play other table games like nine ball or quick fire but I can not play against another player and the screen doesn't load.  I have looked for several sites, downloaded what I read, changed browser to Chromium and tried to correct this problem for several hours and just wonder "am I stupid" ? ?

Could use some support an hoping I get it :)

Comment: The answers here should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334007/i-have-the-newest-adobe-flash-player-but-it-still-wont-work

Comment: This worked ! the Pepper flash worked after I tried the flash and java as instructed to download as plugins :D thanks so much and after all the time I spend reading about this IT FEELS GOOD TO HAVE SOMETHING work that I did in my new operation system :D :D thanks

Comment: searchfgold6789: Please post your answer as an answer so that Bobcat can accept it.

Comment: @jdthood I marked this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Flash player is no longer supported for linux. Some games require newer version of flash player than the last supported. However, you can use google chrome, as it has the built-in flash player that's the newest version.

Comment: The answers here should help: askubuntu.com/questions/334007/… –  searchfgold6789 ! I did the pepper flash and it worked in chrome ! Like the Song by P. Williams Because I'm happy :D "I'm listening to it right now btw" thanks for your help :D clap along if you feel like this is what ya want to do . . . Oh and the version of flash player was Adobe Flash Player (2 files) - Version: 12.0.0.77